Characterization of Vilenkin group
It is shown in  [1, Section 1] by C.W. Onneweer that every infinite compact, metrizable, zero-dimensional commutative group is a Vilenkin group. My question is does this implication also hold if we omit the commutativity of the group, i.e.,
Question: Is it known that every infinite compact, metrizable, zero-dimensional group is also a Vilenkin group? If not, is there any counter example known for it?
A Vilenkin group is defined as follows:
Definition: A group $G$ is called a Vilenkin group if it possesses a strictly decreasing sequence of compact open normal subgroups $G:=G_0\supset G_1\supset G_2\supset \ldots$ such that

$2\leq \left|G_n/G_{n+1}\right| =:\kappa_n < \infty$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$,
$\langle G_n\rangle_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ is a basis of neighbourhoods at the identity element $e$ of $G$, and $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}G_n =\{e\}$.

Thanks in advance for providing any relevant reference or input in this direction.
Referred article: Onneweer, C. W., Absolute convergence of Fourier series on certain groups, Duke Math. J. 39, 599-609 (1972). ZBL0252.43016.

Yes it's true, see any basic text on profinite groups. (For instance, this is proved in the first 10 lines of the book Galois cohomology by J-P. Serre.)

Thanks! It's clear now.
